# c++ GetKeyState() some Key codes not working

Tags: c++, windows, input

Hi i am creating a game in c++ on Windows7 and have came over a strange problem:

I use GetKeyState for retrieving key states and it has worked fine till now.

I have mapped a few keys: (INPUTKEY is integer)

```
   const static INPUTKEY KEY_W = 87;
   const static INPUTKEY KEY_S = 83;
   const static INPUTKEY KEY_A = 65;
   const static INPUTKEY KEY_D = 68;
   const static INPUTKEY KEY_I = 73; // this one is not working
   const static INPUTKEY KEY_V = 86;
```

and i cant get Key "I" working it just returns that it is not pressed 0X0000

here is my get function:

```
    inline static bool isKeyPressed(int keyCode){
        return (GetKeyState(keyCode) & 0x8000);
    }
```

Does anyone know what could be the cause. I have nothing related to Key I in my window MESSAGES loop...

here is the window loop:

```
void Window::run() {
    MSG msg;
    displayState = 1;
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

}

LRESULT CALLBACK Window::WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
     Window* window = ((Window*) GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));

     switch(message) {
           case WM_PAINT:
           DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
           break;
     case WM_CLOSE:
          window->isCloseRequestedBool = true;
          break;
     case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
          window->getMousePressState()->leftMouse = true;
          DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
          break;
     case WM_LBUTTONUP:
           window->getMousePressState()->leftMouse = false;
           DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
           break;
     case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
           window->getMousePressState()->rightMouse = true;
           DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
           break;
     case WM_RBUTTONUP:
           window->getMousePressState()->rightMouse = false;
           DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
           break;
     case WM_MBUTTONDOWN:
           window->getMousePressState()->middleMouse = true;
           DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
           break;
     case WM_MBUTTONUP:
           window->getMousePressState()->middleMouse = false;
           DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
           break;
     case WM_DESTROY:
          window->Destroy();
          PostQuitMessage(0);
          window->displayState = 0;
          return 0;
      default:
          return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
```

}